# Is it safe to work under ubuntu live session?

Tags: boot, live-usb

Hello I was wondering whether its more safe and virus resistant to work under the Ubuntu live session than having installed Ubuntu on my hdd

- Firstly I would wipe the hdd
- Each time I would like to do something on my PC I will just boot the live Ubuntu
- All of my files will be on another USB stick
- Goal of this would be to prevent me from viruses and other things since nothing will be saved

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44916/discussion-on-answer-by-rinzwind-is-it-safe-to-work-under-ubuntu-live-session).

Answer (score 6):

> Hello i was wondering whether its more safe and virus resistant to work under the ubuntu live session than having installed ubuntu on my hdd

- There are zero active virusses so this statement is a fallacy.
- Mind that your question is probably wrong too: a virus is a specific type of malware. One that spreads itself over computers. Ransomware, rootkits and other crap are not virusses. The goal of ransomware is to hijack your system and extort money. rootkits are created to fish out email addresses and credit cards details. Those 2 specifically target 1 machine.

> Is it safe to work under ubuntu live session?

Yes. 2 comments:

- it is slow as hell.
- it adds not a lot of extra safety compared to a normal install.

When you use a normal installation and abide by a few simple rules you will never run into irrecoverable problems.  Virusses come roughly from 2 locations: mail and downloads. BOTH locations you can regulate.

- use on-line mail. Don't download attachments you do not know the origins of
- don't download software randomly. Use Ubuntu software center. Only when you really need something specific (like apache or mysql) go to the source website and then make darn sure that site is legit.
- use a couple of add-ons for your browser to verify websites. ispprotection is also a tool for that.
- use a good admin password. As long as that is safe so is the core of your system.
- create backups of your personal data and store it on several different locations (an USB you keep in the cupboard , in the cloud).

Also think about it:  Getting a system broken is not the problem. Any system can get compromised if the attacker really really wants to.

Getting your system back up and running as it was is the real challenge when that happens.

---

If you are really paranoid install 2 rootkit hunters (1 is not enough since they give far too many false positives). But people that use rootkits tend to do this for profit; they want lists of 100000 emails, creditcards and the likes. Chances are you and me are not a target.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44916/discussion-on-answer-by-rinzwind-is-it-safe-to-work-under-ubuntu-live-session).